# Eclipe mars error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I downloaded Eclipse Mars and on start I get the error below:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Setup check...".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: user:/user.setup; systemId: user:/user.setup; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
```

Anybody knows what causing the error? and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Correct workspace solved the problem.
I had 2 workspaces and one of them was the correct one and choose that one solved it.

Thanks

Comment: I got a similar error, but your workaround didn't work for me.. can anyone suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can try and install using the Oomph installer instead of extracting from a zip.This fixed the problem for me.